# SlideAction Icon color need to change - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, icons

Using below package in Flutter :
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable/example

There in code you will find below widget:

```
SlidableAction(
                onPressed: doNothing,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0392CF),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icons.save,
                label: 'Save',
              ),
```

Now Please note that **icon** property has Icons.save which is inbuilt and coming from flutter inbuilt sdk package.

Now, I want to change the color of that Icon. I have tried using `Icons()` widget but it only accept **Icons.any_inbuild_icon** name as a value.

How can I change the color of that Slidable Icon? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**foregroundColor** is the color of the icon. so change the value of foreground and it works for me.

foregroundColor: Colors.white,

CHANGE TO WHATEVER COLOR YOU WANT
example:
Colors.red or pass hex value  Color(0xDE00FF00)

[VIEW CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxATp.png)

[VIEW RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awUV9.png)